# Magento: how to add content to <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('outer-right') ?>

Tags: magento, templates, magento-1.7, php

I'm still struggling with magento.
I have a 3 column layout but want to place yet another
widget in the outer right of the content with
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('outer-right') ?>` .

How do I create a .phtml file with the stuff to be output
when `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('outer-right') ?>`
is invoked?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the term widget generically, or are you referring to Magento's CMS widget feature?

Comment: Possibly relevant to your interestes (but not worth a real answer) is No Frills Magento Layout.  This is an ebook I wrote that explains Magento's layout system top-to-bottom, (which is hard to do in a single Stack Overflow question) http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout

Comment: Sorry if I used the whole terms. I am not trying to add any sophisticated widget. Just add some html.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add/stuff  your blocks via your layout.xml file inside a block called 'outer-right' in the correct layout handle. When your layout handle is active you will be able to fetch its html by getChildHtml('outer-right')

```
<cms_index_index>
<block type="core/template" name="outer-right" template="xyz.phtml">
   <block type="core/template" name="inside-outer-right-1" template="inside.phtml"/>
   <block type="core/template" name="inside-outer-right-2" template="inside2.phtml"/> 
</block>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am confused. What is xyz.phtml, inside.phtml, inside2.phtml ? And what is cms_index_index?

Comment: Also, where do I put this code. Idelly I would be able to code a layout update, but how?

Comment: How can I extend cms.xml to do the following. Do I have to copy over the whole cms.xml file to my layout directory or can I extend it withot copying it?

Comment: What do the cms_index_* handles inside the base/default/layout/cms.xml do?